# Return the company with most film in a genre

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, inner-join, window-functions

I am working on this project at my university, where I need to create a query to the database. I want the query to return the company with most movies in the given genre. At the moment I have this query, but this only return one company, but there can probably be more than one.

```
SELECT CompanyID, CategoryID, COUNT(*) as NumberOfMovies
FROM Movie
    NATURAL JOIN CategoryFilm
    NATURAL JOIN Category
    NATUAL JOIN Comapny
    GROUP BY CategoryID, CompanyID
    Order by NumberOfMovies DESC LIMIT 1
```

I beleave I will need a "having" in here.

Comment: So you have some data and when you run this select statement on that data you get one row back and you expect more than one ? Do you think we should have one part of that data so we can try to help you ? And please , with that data, do add your expected results and share with us what database do you use ?

Comment: @Jonas, pls check if it helps

Answer (score 0):

pls try this, it may because you added `limit 1`, which only show 1st retrieved record

```
SELECT CompanyID, CategoryID, COUNT(*) as NumberOfMovies
FROM Movie
    NATURAL JOIN CategoryFilm
    NATURAL JOIN Category
    NATURAL JOIN Comapny
    GROUP BY CategoryID, CompanyID
    Order by NumberOfMovies DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "category" you mean "genre" -- or that they are the same thing.

Do not use `NATURAL JOIN`.  It does not even use properly declared foreign key relationships, instead relying merely on name similarity between tables.  It is dangerous because the columns used are not specified and can introduce hard-to-debug errors.  I often refer to it as an "abomination" because it does not take table declarations into account.

If you have a given category, then I would expect a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT CompanyID, COUNT(*) as NumberOfMovies
FROM Movie m JOIN
     CategoryFilm cf
     ON cf.movie_id = m.movie_id JOIN
     Company c
     ON c.company_id = m.company_id
WHERE cf.category_id = ?
GROUP BY CategoryID
ORDER BY NumberOfMovies DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow ties, you can use window function `rank()`:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        co.companyID,
        ca.categoryID,
        count(*) NumberOfMovies,
        rank() over(partition by c.categoryID order by count(*) desc) rn
    from movie m
    inner join categoryFilm cf on cf.movieID = m.movieID
    inner join category ca     on ca.categoryID = cf.categoryID
    inner join company co      on co.companyID = m.companyID
    group by co.companyID, ca.categoryID
) t
where rn = 1
order by ca.categoryID
```

This gives you the top company for each and every category, ties included. If you want to filter on a given category, you can just add a `where` clause to the inner query.

Side note: do not use `natural join`s: they are error-prone. I rewrote the query to use `inner join`s instead (I made a few assumptions on the relations).